# How can you update a integer inside of a while loop?

Tags: python

I'm new and trying to figure out a problem. I don't know how to update a variable inside of a while loop. I tried to google and search it on stack overflow but since I'm new, I can't understand what they are saying.

```
while x >= one : 
    x * (x - 1)
   x >= continue
```

I'm not sure if this is formatted incorrectly or what but it does not update.

I tried to change it a few times but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: There are no assignments, and `continue` is a statement, not a variable. You should probably review the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: `x * (x - 1)` should be `x = (x - 1)`.

Comment: It's not clear what you intended with `x >= continue`.

Comment: Updating a variable inside a loop is the same as updating it outside a loop, you use `=` to assign a new value to it.

Comment: It's asking to solve a factorial, so would x * (x - 1) be wrong still? I'm not sure what i meant with the continue, I did it late at night. When I run it, the variable does not update and redo in the loop again as the new number.

Comment: The x * (x-1) will not work, even if you wrote `x = x * (x-1)` because this will grow to infinity... Take an example. x = 3. Now we do x = 3 * 2. Now x = 6. Now in the next iteration, x = 6 * 5 = 30. Next time x = 30 * 29 = 870... etc. We need a seperate variable to have the decrement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a wild guess, but are you trying to make a factorial function? Then, using the most similar approach to what you're already doing, should be:

```
def factorial(n):
    """
    Computes n * (n-1) * (n-2) * ... * 2 * 1
    """
    current_multiply = n-1
    while current_multiply > 1:
        n *= current_multiply
        current_multiply -= 1
    
    return n if n > 0 else None
```

This will take an integer as an input and return that input factorial. Yes, it does say 0! is None but that can easily be fixed.

All of this ignores that there is already a builtin factorial function in the math library.

Comment: Yes it is for a factorial function. It is a question on a coding website.